# Points A, B and C have position vectors a = i + 2 j, b = 2i + j and c = 2i − 3 j. Find the shortest distance from B to line AC

Tags: geometry, vectors, vector-analysis, solution-verification

Points A, B and C have position vectors a = i + 2 j, b = 2i + j and c = 2i − 3 j. Find:

> The shortest distance from B to line AC
>
> The area of triangle ABC

What I have done so far:

Found **AB** and **AC** and hence, the vector resolute of **AB** in the direction of **AC**.
According to my working out this is 3/13 (i - 5j).

From here onwards, I'm not sure how to construct a diagram/show the working out to get the shortest distance from B to line **AC**. The answer key shows the shortest distance is obtained by:

**AB** - 3/13 (i - 5j)

^^How does this come about though? From here, I can work out the area of the triangle formed by A, B & C.

Any tips/help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\mathbf {AB}$ can be resolved into perpendicular components:  one is along $\mathbf{AC}$ and one is perpendicular to that; the length of the one perpendicular to that is the shortest distance from $B$ to line $AC$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The area of $\triangle ABC$ given $2D$ coordinates 
of the vertices $(A_x,A_y),\ (B_x,B_y),\ (C_x,C_y)$
is given by
\begin{align} 
S_{ABC}
&=
\tfrac12\,|(B_x-A_x)(C_y-A_y)-(C_x-A_x)(B_y-A_y)|
\\
&=
\tfrac12\,|(2-1)(-3-2)-(2-1)(1-2)|
=2
.
\end{align}

The shortest distance from the point $B$ to the line $AC$
is the altitude $|BD|$ of $\triangle ABC$,
so given that the area $S_{ABC}$ of $\triangle ABC$, 
can be also expressed as
\begin{align}
S_{ABC}&=\tfrac12\cdot|AC|\cdot|BD|
\end{align}

we can find it as

\begin{align}
|BD|&=
\frac{2\,S_{ABC}}{|AC|}
=\frac{2\cdot2}{\sqrt{26}}
=\tfrac2{13}\,\sqrt{26}
\approx 0.78446454
.
\end{align}

Note that we don't actually need to find the coordinates of the point $D$,
if we just need the distance $|BD|$.

Answer (score 0):

We can  find the length of **AB** and then project it onto the line **AC** and then applying Pythagoras' theorem find the third side of the triangle which is the shortest distance of **B** from **AC**

$ |{\bf AB}|=|{\bf i-  j}| =\sqrt{2}\\
\frac{{\bf AB}.{\bf AC}}{|{\bf AC}|}=\frac{6}{\sqrt{26}}$

Thus the shortest distance is $\sqrt{2-\frac{36}{26}} =\frac{4}{\sqrt{26}}$